# How to avoid 'Unassigned Local Variable' defined inside a try-catch block

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

This is one error that I regularly face. Although I manage to circumvent it using some way or another, it really annoys me.
In the code snippet below, I want to safe guard against exceptions from myRequest.GetResponse()

```
        WebRequest myRequest = WebRequest.Create(baseUri.OriginalString);
        WebResponse myResponse;
        Stream myStream;
        StreamReader reader;
        try
        {
            myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
            myStream = myResponse.GetResponseStream();
            reader = new StreamReader(myStream);
        }
        catch (WebException status)
        {
            txtConsole.AppendText("Error in GetLinks::WebException\n" + status.Response);
            txtConsole.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        }
        catch
        {
            txtConsole.AppendText("Some error in GetLinks");
            txtConsole.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        Regex regex = new Regex(@"\s*(?i)href\s*=\s*(\""([^""]*\"")|'[^']*'|([^'"">\s]+))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        MatchCollection splits = regex.Matches(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

Now, when I try to build/compile the code, it says

> "Use of unassigned local variable 'reader'"

Now my question, if try statement runs smoothly without any exceptions being thrown, why can't the compiler access the value assigned to reader inside the try block?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are using a variable, that is assigned in a try/catch block, outside that block. You'll want to move the whole code into the try block.

You could assign `null` to it like @Svexo proposed, but this will throw an exception should the stream error out.

Comment: I used to move everything inside try block. But then I realized I couldn't do that always. However, assigning it to null and then checking for NULL exception after the catch statement is what I need to do.

Comment: Your use of `reader` after the try block reveals a dependency: your code depends on the correct return of the try block. By definition, this should be included in the try block. 

When that becomes unmanageable, you'll have to use `null` and then hope you always check for null.

Answer (score 8):

The compiler says `use of unassigned variable` because the code after the try/catch block will be executed anyway.

If you have an exception, you catch it, then you run the code after it. That's why you get this error.

You can either

- assign `null` to the local variables and then test if they're null before executing the rest of the code
- return the function in your catch block.
- or move all the code into the try block as suggested @Femaref

Answer (score 2):

```
 WebRequest myRequest = WebRequest.Create(baseUri.OriginalString);
 WebResponse myResponse = null;
 Stream myStream= null;
 StreamReader reader =null;
```

This will assign the variables

Edit:

If you do it like this you should add an if outside your try/catch

```
if(reader != null)
{
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"\s*(?i)href\s*=\s*(\""([^""]*\"")|'[^']*'|([^'"">\s]+))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        MatchCollection splits = regex.Matches(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Do note in your case its better to put everything in the try/catch block

Comment: This will result in NullPointer exception when the reader is not assigned due to error with the stream.